# C# Adding dataobject to all service in an existing project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I have an Asp.Net Core 3.1 existing project with 50 to 60 services in the BusinessLayer. Now the business rule has changed so I need to check every method of every service particular logic to make sure the user can do something.

For that I need to get some dataobject like say

```
UserPermission userPermission
```

from the ControllerBase to the Service Class. This object needs to be set in the ControllerBase and used in every one of the Service Class methods

How do I do that without making a lots of changes to all the Controllers or Services without making any changes to method signature.

I did lookup this article [(http://rion.io/2016/01/04/accessing-identity-info-using-dependency-injection-in-net-5/)](http://rion.io/2016/01/04/accessing-identity-info-using-dependency-injection-in-net-5/) which is talking about something like that

If this is fine, do I need to use as Resolver without any interface or should I use Interface and implementation

Here is what I currently doing and which is working

Added a interface with two method like this

```
public interface IService
    {
        UserPermission GetProperty();
        void SetProperty(UserPermission userPermission);
    }
```

In the class

```
 public class Service : IService
    {
        UserPermission _userPermission;
      
        public UserPermission GetUserPermission ()
        {
            return _userPermission;
        }

        public void SetUserPermission (UserPermission userPermission)
        {
            this._userPermission= userPermission;
        }
    }
```

In the StartUp.cs

```
 services.AddScoped<IService, Service>();
```

In every controller I inject IService and pass on to the BaseController where it sets the value of UserPermission  IService's using SetUserPermission() method

and in every service I inject IService and get the value of UserPermission using  IService's using GetUserPermission() method

This works but, I would like to validate this method or find out a better way to accomplish this.

Thank you for your time

Comment: What is your UserPermission?If you want to get this in the BaseController,just inject it like your `Service` did.

Comment: It's just a class with one property with setter/getter

Answer (score 0):

1.If the model data is **dynamic**,you could use a constructor like below:

```
public class UserPermission
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Role { get; set; }
    public UserPermission(int id,string name,string role)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
        Role = role;
    }
}
```

Get the value like below:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly UserPermission UserPermission = new UserPermission(1, "aaa", "asd");

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = this.UserPermission;
        return View();
    }
}
```

Result:
[image]

2.If the model data is **constant**,just set the value in the model:

```
public class UserPermission
{
    public int Id { get; set; } = 1;
    public string Name { get; set; } = "aa";
    public string Role { get; set; } = "bbb";  
}
```

You could get value like below:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new UserPermission();
        return View();
    }
}
```

Result:
[image]